# Using javascript while clicking a hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, hyperlink

i have a settings page on my user profile system.

**The HTML** (settings.php)

```
<div id="set-list">
  <div class="set-cont" action="account">
  Account Settings
  </div>
  <div class="set-cont" action="privacy">
  Privacy Settings  
  </div>
</div>
<div id="set-show">
           //account settings html form
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.set-cont').click(function(){
    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    $.get('getSettingsHTML.php',{
          action : action
    },function(data){
       $('#set-show').html(data.output);
    },'json');
});
```

**PHP**(getSettingsHTML.php)

```
    <?php
    $output="";
  switch($_GET['action']){
    case 'account':
          $output .='<input type="text" id="firstname">"';
            //blah blah many stuffs
    break;
    case 'privacy':
       $output .='<input type="text" id="email" >';
    break;
    }
    echo json_encode(array("output"=>$output));

    ?>
```

when the page loads Accont setting's html form is loaded from default.
when anyone clicks a `.set-cont` its `action` attribute it taken and hence the appropriate form is loaded from php.

Now if i want to load Privacy Settings I have to click the one in `.set-cont`.

If i have a link like `<a href="settings.php">Privacy Settings</a>`. The account settings will be loaded and you have to click on *Privacy Settings*  menu to load the form.

Is there any way i can do `$('.set-cont[action="privacy"]').trigger('click')` right from the `a` element or maybe any alternative ?

Comment: Is the anchor tag coming inside the `<div></div>`?

Comment: did not get you @ICanHasKittenz ?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand what it is your asking but perhaps your link could be settings.php#privacy and then when the settings.php loads you can use JS to detect that hash value and load the correct form.

Comment: @HackerManiac What I meant was, you want to give an `<a>` tag instead of clicking on the div. So is it going to be like: `<div class="set-cont" action="privacy"><a href="settings.php">Privacy Settings </a></div>` or only the anchor tags?

Comment: no thats not i want! perhaps @Boreded understood what i wanted.

Comment: Am I right in thinking the link is coming from a different page? and you want to be able to do load either Privacy or Account settings? If so, I shall submit an answer for you with an example.

Comment: you may present with an answer @Boreded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to link to settings.php from another page and when the page loads you want to be able to specify which form is loaded, either Privacy or Account settings.

If so you could do something like the following:

```
<a href="settings.php#privacy">Privacy Settings</a>
```

and then on Settings.php you have the following **jQuery**:

```
$(function() {
   if (window.location.hash) {
       var action = window.location.hash.substring(1);
       loadForm(action);
   }
});

$('.set-cont').click(function() {
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    loadForm(action);
});

function loadForm(action) {
    $.get('getSettingsHTML.php',{
        action : action
    },function(data){
        $('#set-show').html(data.output);
    },'json');
}
```

Comment: `loadForm(action)` is receiving `#privacy` as `action` and not `privacy` @boreded

Comment: @HackerManiac please see updated answer. That should do the trick.

Comment: can you please explain reason for using `$(function(){});` because the stuff inside that function can be run normally ?

Comment: It is the shorthand for jQuerys document ready. Anything inside that function gets executed after the page has fully loaded. Please see the [jQuery website](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) for more info. In this case the 'set-show' div may not be loaded when we execute loadForm and so to ensure it is we put it in this function.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically clicking a link is not supported. What you could do is when the link is clicked, create a form and submit it:

### HTML

```
<div class="set-cont" action="privacy">
    <a href="settings.php">Privacy Settings</a>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$('.set-cont > a').on("click", function()
{
    var action = $(this).parent("div").attr('action'),
        href = $(this).attr('href');

    var form = $("<form></form>");
    form.attr(
    {
        id     : "newform",
        action : href + "?action=" + action,
        method : "GET",
        target : "_blank"        // Eventually open in new window/tab
    });

    $("body").append(form);
    $("#newform").submit();
    $("#newform").remove();
});
```

Comment: this is notwhat i asked for! @geenHeek

Comment: @HackerManiac Tone down the attitude. You're getting FREE HELP!

Comment: i apologize @relentless

Answer (score 0):

```
seetting.php->
<div id="set-list">
  <div class="set-cont" action="account">
 <form name="form" class="form" action="url1.php" method="post" id='account_form'>
          <input type="hidden" name="name1" >
           <input type="hidden" name="name2" >
     </form>
  </div>
  <div class="set-cont" action="privacy">
    <form name="form" class="form" action="url2.php" method="post" id='privacy_form'>
          <input type="hidden" name="name1" >
           <input type="hidden" name="name2" >
     </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="set-show">
           //account settings html form
</div>
jquery->
$('.set-cont').on("click", function()
{
    var action = $(this).attr('action');

    if(action=="privacy")
    {
    var formid='privacy_form';
    }
    else if(action=="account")
    {
    var formid='account_form';
    }
    $("#"+formid).submit();

});
```